# Should I use OPcache for simple PHP website

Tags: php, server, opcache

I've a PHP website (all files has .php extension), where most of the pages only contains few (5 to 6) PHP `include` statement to include header, footer, menu, etc. which are common to all pages, and the PHP functions `date()` and `urlencode()`.

My question is should I enable PHP OPcache for my site? Will I get any performance improvement by doing this.

Comment: what is your php version? server info?

Comment: I'm using PHP 7.4

Comment: Yes - your PHP files will be compiled to `p-code` (just once) which will be then kept in RAM. Thus you will avoid reading/interpreting your files for each HTTP request.

Comment: Do you mean whole php file will be cached in RAM and serve directly from cache and apache won't transfer request to PHP-FPM for processing?